# Convert Matlab Console output to new expression

Tags: matlab

In order to debug a very complex set of functions, I want to isolate a subfunction from the workspace in order to make different test. Therefore a need selected values from the function workspace to be defined already. By setting a break point at the specific position I can "look" into the current workspace by displaying the values in the console, like the variable `HF33`

```
HF33 =

     1.0777    0.0865    0.0955
    -0.1891    0.8110   -0.1889
     0.0935    0.0846    1.0755
```

Is there some function / script that could convert this result to a new Matlab expression that can be pasted somewhere else (for example at the head of a new script), e.g.:

```
HF33 = [ 1.0777,  0.0865,  0.0955;
        -0.1891,  0.8110, -0.1889;
         0.0935,  0.0846,  1.0755 ];
```

With that I could test the subfunction and its behavior by easily changing the given values and see whats happening without having the huge debug workspace running.

Is there some easy function like `res2exp(HF33)`?

Comment: Could you provide some background on the purpose of this? Do you want to get just matrices in a format that is again executable or any console output? Do you need the full numerical precision?

Comment: And you really want to have it visually like that? Otherwise you could just `save` it as variable like `save result.mat` and in your other script you `load result.mat` - otherwise you could surely write a text-file looking like you want, but aiming what?

Comment: No, its for debugging purposes. I want to test a subfunction and therefore want to copy selected values from the local workspace in order to insert them as numerical values to a new script. Then I can change the values if wanted such that I have a new test script.

Comment: The approach you're trying to adopt is extremely error-prone and I recommend to use other debugging methods.

Comment: Maybe. Nevertheless under some circumstances the function I am looking for might be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Create this function to get the variable name

```
function out = varname(var)
out = inputname(1);
end
```

you can print it direct to console:

```
fprintf('%s =%s\n',varname(varToSave),mat2str(varToSave));
```

Or use fopen and fprint to write it in a file

```
fop = fopen('filename','w');
fprint(fop,'%s = %s' ,varname(varToSave),mat2str(varToSave));
fclose(fop);
```

I think this will help you

Comment: As first start that one might be useful, but this can also be obtained by simply copying the console output. I am looking for a conversion that adds the symbols like `[,;]` and also inserts the `varname = ` command.

Comment: kromuchi, using these functions you can automate the process without hardcording! 

Try these and tell me, if this solved your problem

Comment: Thank you for your modified answer. Yes, the `mat2str` command did the magic. Together with your `varname`-function I even get the name of the variable. I think that should work quite fine.

Answer (score 2):

I made this up just now. It is not formatted beautifully, but it achieves what you are trying to do - if I understand you correctly.

```
a = [ 2 3 4 5
4 5 5 6
3 4 5 6];


fprintf('\nb = [\n\n');
disp(a); 
fprintf(']\n\n');
```

Copy and paste this and see if it does what you want. It's also very simple code, so you could modify it if the spacing and newline characters aren't where you want them.

You could also make a small function out of this if you wanted to.

If you want me to make a function of it, let me know... I can do it tomorrow. But you can probably figure it out.

Ehh, I just made the function. It didn't take long.

```
function reprint_matrix(matrix)

    var_name = inputname(1);

    fprintf('\n%s = [\n\n', var_name);
    disp(matrix); 
    fprintf(']\n\n');

end
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be a function like `mat2str()` you are looking for but it will not give exactly the printout you are asking for. Here is an example of how it could be used:

```
>> A = magic(4)

A =

    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1

>> B = mat2str(A)

B =

[16 2 3 13;5 11 10 8;9 7 6 12;4 14 15 1]
```

And if you want the output to be totally copy/paste-able you could use:

```
disp(['C = ',mat2str(A)])
C = [16 2 3 13;5 11 10 8;9 7 6 12;4 14 15 1]
```

Comment: Thanks. That was quite the function I was looking for. The declaration of the variable name `C = ` still has to be written by hand but that is affordable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are looking for, but I think this will help you:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24447-generate-m-file-code-for-any-matlab-variable/content/examples/html/gencode_example.html

Did not use it because I use mat-files to transfer data.

You can combine it with the clipboard function:

`clipboard('copy',gencode(ans))`

Answer (score 0):

Though there are several ways to write variables to text, saving variables as text is definitely bad practice if it can be avoided. Hence, the best advice I can give you is to solve your problem in a different way.

Suppose you want to use `HF33` in your subfunction, then here is what I would recommend:

First of all, save your variable of interest:

```
save HF33 HF33
```

Then when you are in the function where you want to use this variable:

```
load HF33
```

This assumes that your working directory (not workspace) is the same in both cases, but otherwise you can simply add the path in your `save` or `load` command. If you want to display it you can now simply call the variable `HF33` without a semicolon (this is probably the only safe way to display it exactly the way you expect in all cases).

Note that this method can easily be adapted to transfer multiple variables at once.

Comment: Note that if desirable, you can alter the contents of the variable after you load it to enable easy testing. 'Having' a variable visually does not require saving it visually.

Comment: In general you're right. Of course it's convenient to save variables as `mat` files to your hard disc drive. But sometimes the quick copying of variables from one workspace into another needs a faster solution.